# I want to check if the Correct BusinessException is thrown with unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

This is my method in the controller.

```
public ActionResult DeleteModelAliasData(string alias)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.LogModelStateError();
        throw new BusinessException("COMMON_ERROR");
    }

    var response = _vehicleDataBusinessService.DeleteModelAliasData(alias);
    return Json(response);
}
```

I am new at unit testing and I want to write the unit test that when the "`!ModelState.IsValid`" then the exception is thrown, I want to check that is it the correct exception which I Wanted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same as shown in below code.

```
 var ex = Assert.Throws<BusinessException>(() => controller.DeleteModelAliasData(alias));
 Assert.That(ex.Message, Is.EqualTo("COMMON_ERROR"));
```

Reference: **[NUnit Exception Asserts](http://nunit.org/docs/2.5/exceptionAsserts.html)**

---

**Update:**

```
[Test]
public void TestDeleteModelAliasData()
{
    // Get your controller instance - you know it better how to instantiate
    var controller = GetControllerInstance();

    // Add error message to ModelState
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "Error Message");

    var alias = "sampleAlias";

    // As ModelState is having an Error, the method should throw BusinessException
    var ex = Assert.Throws<BusinessException>(() => controller.DeleteModelAliasData(alias));

    // Exception is raised, assert the message if you want
    Assert.That(ex.Message, Is.EqualTo("COMMON_ERROR"));
}
```

Comment: Could you write the unit test for this method so i can understand it better

Comment: Thank you ... it really helped me

Comment: @VeepPatel you can mark it as answer if this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

The default value for `ModelState.IsValid` is `true` when the model state dictionary is empty.

That would mean that in order for the method under test to flow in the desired path you would need to make sure that the model state behaves as expected.

This can be done by adding a model error to the model state

For example

```
//Arrange

//...initialize controller and its dependencies

//add model error to force IsValid to be false.
controller.ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "Error Message");

var alias = string.Empty;
var expectedErrorMessage = "COMMON_ERROR";

//Act
Action act = () => controller.DeleteModelAliasData(alias);

//Assert
Assert.That(act, Throws.TypeOf<BusinessException>()
                 .With.Message.EqualTo(expectedErrorMessage));
```

You would then assert that the expected exception is thrown with the expected values.

Reference [ThrowsConstraint](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/ThrowsConstraint)